# Ubuntu desktop is bonking

Tags: unity

I have a computer currently has 3 monitors. I just rebooted it and now the desktop is goofing. As shown in screenshot the background does not look right and I right click the desktop and it does nothing. I tried going into display settings and change desktop background and the background didnt even change! Not sure if desktop icon stuff were loaded or not because I don't never have none.

[image]

edited later: I have restarted again and the desktop was all black so then I rebooted the computer again. background  loads but oh my word my computer is SOO glitchy! i had to force quit the computer twice and restart. That's not too hot :(

The last thing I want to do is reinstall cuz i just spend days getting my data back on and setting the computer up, to reinstall would waste all that time. And I dont have much of it :(

Edited further at the request of Terrance:

the output of xrandr --current is:

```
james@james-toshiba:~$ xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.02*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
james@james-toshiba:~$
```

resolution: 1366 x 768 on all of them I think

Comment: I have bumped into this before, and I had to write a script in startup to fix it.  What is the resolution that you are running on your monitors?  Also, what is the output of `xrandr --current`?

Comment: If you could update your question with this information.  Thank you!

Comment: It looks like screen overlap on the resolutions that you are getting, however, your xrandr output isn't showing that, nor is it showing all three monitors.  More like they are in a mirrored mode overlapping somehow.   Do you have a NVIDIA card in your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, which version of Ubuntu are you running?
Second, check if graphics driver(s) have not been deleted. To do it, just run

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

If apt-get tells you that's updated, the problem is another one. If apt-get tells you that it's not installed or you can update it, do it. Then reboot.

Try to detach monitors and run a game (maybe Tux Games) with 1 monitor. Maybe your graphics card is not enough powerful to handle 3 monitors.

Comment: video-intel if you have Intel cards, otherwise search your drivers on the web

Comment: I'll try that when I get home, I am on my zorin os here at work.

Comment: k I'm home. My version is Xenial Xerus. I tried supertuxkart with 1 monitor and it worked. Also the output of Rocco's command is

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version (2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1).
xserver-xorg-video-intel set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
james@james-toshiba:~$

Comment: The problem is the big amount of monitors. Try with 2 monitors. If it works, then your card isn't capable to handle the 3rd monitor. Leave vote if helped!

Comment: no!!! I said that I tried with one monitor and it is still bonking!

Comment: also I dont have enough reputation to vote :(

Comment: I'm giving up. no one is helping and there is no reason why this ubuntu unity should be doing this. I have installed GNOME shell and ubuntu-gnome-desktop and am just going to use GNOME 3 instead.